# LEFT OUTER JOIN mysql - почему-то не работает запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Пытаюсь составить запрос в бд mysql. В бд есть таблицы `label_person` (метки) и `answers` (ответы). И таблица `people` (люди), к которой они относятся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У `Людей` (конкретно одного человека) может не быть записей в таблицах `Ответы` и `Метки`. Мне же нужно получить все данные, а если `Ответа` или `Метки` нет - оставить поле пустым.

Составил запрос, выполняю - пусто, не возвращает ни одной строчки. Если удалить из запроса таблицу `label_person`, то всё работает. Что я делаю не так?

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(prefixes.name, samples.number) AS sample_number,
  CONCAT(genes.name, polfzms.name) AS polfzm,
  CONCAT(alleles.name, '/', alleles_1.name) AS allelic_variant,
  questions.text,
  answers.value,
  people.surname,
  people.first_name,
  people.middle_name,
  people.birth_date,
  people.gender,
  people.id AS person_id,
  labels.name AS label_name
FROM samples
  INNER JOIN prefixes
    ON samples.prefix_id = prefixes.id
  INNER JOIN providers
    ON samples.provider_id = providers.id
  INNER JOIN polfzm_sample
    ON polfzm_sample.sample_id = samples.id
  INNER JOIN polfzms
    ON polfzm_sample.polfzm_id = polfzms.id
  INNER JOIN genes
    ON polfzms.gene_id = genes.id
  INNER JOIN genotypes
    ON polfzm_sample.genotype_id = genotypes.id
  INNER JOIN alleles
    ON genotypes.l_allele_id = alleles.id
  INNER JOIN alleles alleles_1
    ON genotypes.r_allele_id = alleles_1.id
  INNER JOIN people
    ON samples.person_id = people.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN answers
    ON answers.person_id = people.id
  INNER JOIN questions
    ON answers.question_id = questions.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN label_person
    ON label_person.person_id = people.id
  INNER JOIN labels
    ON label_person.label_id = labels.id
WHERE label_person.label_id IN (5)
GROUP BY CONCAT(prefixes.name, samples.number),
         CONCAT(genes.name, polfzms.name),
         CONCAT(alleles.name, '/', alleles_1.name),
         questions.text,
         answers.value,
         people.surname,
         people.first_name,
         people.middle_name,
         people.birth_date,
         people.gender,
         people.id,
         labels.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно условие по `label_person` переместить в `ON` (так как в WHERE он превращает связь фактически в INNER JOIN), а также заменить `INNER JOIN labels` на `LEFT OUTER JOIN labels` (поскольку вы идете к ним через LEFT OUTER).

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(prefixes.name, samples.number) AS sample_number,
  CONCAT(genes.name, polfzms.name) AS polfzm,
  CONCAT(alleles.name, '/', alleles_1.name) AS allelic_variant,
  people.surname,
  people.first_name,
  people.middle_name,
  people.birth_date,
  people.gender,
  people.id AS person_id,
  labels.name
FROM samples
  INNER JOIN prefixes
    ON samples.prefix_id = prefixes.id
  INNER JOIN providers
    ON samples.provider_id = providers.id
  INNER JOIN polfzm_sample
    ON polfzm_sample.sample_id = samples.id
  INNER JOIN polfzms
    ON polfzm_sample.polfzm_id = polfzms.id
  INNER JOIN genes
    ON polfzms.gene_id = genes.id
  INNER JOIN genotypes
    ON polfzm_sample.genotype_id = genotypes.id
  INNER JOIN alleles
    ON genotypes.l_allele_id = alleles.id
  INNER JOIN alleles alleles_1
    ON genotypes.r_allele_id = alleles_1.id
  INNER JOIN people
    ON samples.person_id = people.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN label_person
    ON label_person.person_id = people.id
    AND label_person.label_id IN (5)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN labels
    ON label_person.label_id = labels.id
GROUP BY CONCAT(prefixes.name, samples.number),
         CONCAT(genes.name, polfzms.name),
         CONCAT(alleles.name, '/', alleles_1.name),
         people.surname,
         people.first_name,
         people.middle_name,
         people.birth_date,
         people.gender,
         people.id,
         labels.name
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Дополнил ваш ответ своим кодом, который заработал.